# Why does Azure Devops change the date on dlls downloaded from Nuget?

Tags: azure-devops, nuget

I notice that files such as EntityFramework.Dll are deployed with the current time.
I have been experiencing [this error](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/21406) and I resolved it by copying dlls from my development machine to the overwrite deployed dlls.

What causes the date to change on the dlls?

azure-pipelines.yml is

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**\*.sln'
    feedsToUse: config

    nugetConfigPath: 'MyService.ServiceHost/nuget.config'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: |
     $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\MyService.ServiceHost\bin\debug\**\*.*

    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    artifactName: 'drop'
```

my nuget.config references

and a private feed in https://pkgs.dev.azure.com

[Update]

I tried adding preserveTimestamp: True to the CopyFiles@2 task but it made no difference

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: |
     $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\MyService.ServiceHost\bin\debug\**\*.*
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    preserveTimestamp: True
```

[Update]

Leo advises a work around.
However I am wondering how to unzip the file to release
Currently my release pipeline contains

```
copy C:\azagent\A2\_work\r1\a\_PreMyFolder\drop\MyService.ServiceHost\bin\Debug\*.* "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\MyService Service"
```

Comment: Hi @LeoLiu-MSFT I updated the question.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I did more tests about it, found the task `PublishBuildArtifacts` would also modify the Timestamp. I provided a workaround for this issue, you could check if my updated answer resolve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does Azure Devops change the date on dlls downloaded from Nuget?

That because the **default** value of the **preserveTimestamp** option is **False** in the  [Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    #sourceFolder: # Optional
    #contents: '**' 
    targetFolder: 
    #preserveTimestamp: false # Optional
```

To resolve this issue, you just need change the value to `True`.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
  sourceFolder:
  contents: '**' 
  targetFolder: 
  preserveTimestamp: True
```

**Update:**

> I tried adding preserveTimestamp: True to the CopyFiles@2 task but it
>   made no difference

When I first tested this issue, I found that the `copy task` would modify the `Timestamp` of the file. This is indeed the case. And found a solution using option `preserveTimestamp`. I thought this was the whole issue until Kirsten Greed replied to me that this solution did not work.

I had to test the issue again and found that the `PublishBuildArtifacts` task would also modify the `Timestamp` of the file, but there is no such `preserveTimestamp` option like copy task. We could found some similar thread [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/642546/keep-timestamps-during-publish-and-download-artifa.html) and [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/4827), but none of them gives a solution/workaround.

The workaround I currently think of is that you could try to Bundle the  artifacts in a compressed zip file, then unzip it when you use it.

So, I use the [Archive files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops) instead of the copy task:

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2

  displayName: 'Archive $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestSample\TestSample\bin\Debug'

  inputs:

    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestSample\TestSample\bin\Debug'

    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Test.zip'
```

Then publish this zip file as artifact:

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1

  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
```

Now, I could keep the Timestamp for the files:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Leo. How do I unzip the file as part of the release? I updated the question.

Comment: @KirstenGreed, You could use the task `Extract files`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/extract-files?view=azure-devops to unzip the zip file.

Comment: Thanks I will try it out

Comment: @KirstenGreed, You are always welcome :). Please let me know for free if you have any other question for this issue.

Comment: Oh dear I will have to wait till the weekend to try, I made a real mess. What stress!

Comment: @KirstenGreed, Never mind, just go back when you are free. Have a nice day :)!

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem.  If I zip the files or simply do a Machine File Copy task to the server the date modified is always updated by Azure Dev Ops.

I don't believe is it currently possible to deploy from Dev Ops whilst preserving the date modified of the files.